# Keep track of how many times a recursive function has been called in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, global-variables

I am trying to work on a program that has a function whose parameter is an vector of string. I want to use recursive on that function but everytime the function is called, I want to change the parameter to say for example

```
fun(stringArray[i])
```

where i is the number of time the function has been called.

So in simpler way something like following. But I need to keep track of how many times the function fun has been executed.

```
void fun(){
    cout<<hi;
    if(x!=10)
    fun()
}

int main(){

    fun();
}
```

In this one let's say I want to print it out just 10 times, so want to have a varible that increments, and when reaches 10, it stops. So in general what can I do to keep track of it? I tried using global variables but they don't seem to work with functions. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add a parameter and increment it when recursing.

Comment: I strongly recomend you to take a look at my survey

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've seen quite a mess here so I decided to clear the things out.

**Solution 0: Static Variable**

Consider the code proposed with a small modification

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun()
{
    static int count=1;
    count++;
    cout << "fun() is called " << count << " times" << endl;
    if(count<=10)
    {
            fun();
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "first call" << endl;
    fun();
    cout << "second call" << endl;
    fun();
    cout << "third call" << endl;
    fun();
}
```

resulting in this output:

```
first call
fun() is called 2 times
fun() is called 3 times
fun() is called 4 times
fun() is called 5 times
fun() is called 6 times
fun() is called 7 times
fun() is called 8 times
fun() is called 9 times
fun() is called 10 times
fun() is called 11 times
second call
fun() is called 12 times
third call
fun() is called 13 times
```

As you can see, using static variables could lead to some unexpected behaviour.

This is a **one shot function** that will cause you quite some headaches in the future.
Furthermore, the usage of static variables leads to an unreadable code that is error prone

**Just don't do it!**

**Solution 1: Variable passed by value**

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(int i){
    cout<<i<<endl;
    if(i!=3) {
        i++;
        fun(i);
        fun(i);
    }
}

int main(){
    fun(0);
}
```

This is the output:

```
0
1
2
3
3
2
3
3
1
2
3
3
2
3
3
```

As you can see the output is not the number of times the function is called

**Solution 2: Variable passed by reference**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(int& x){
    if(x>=10)
        return;
    ++x;
    cout << x << endl;
    fun(x);
}

void funEntry(){
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Entry point" << endl;
    fun(x);
}

int main(){
    funEntry();
    funEntry();
}
```

will print

```
Entry point
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

This approach will work also with some more exotic recursive pattern like this one

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(int i, int& x){
    if(i>=4)
        return;
    ++x;
    cout << i << " " << x << endl;
    fun(i+1,x);
    fun(i+2,x);
}

void funEntry(){
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Entry point" << endl;
    fun(0,x);
}

int main(){
    funEntry();
    funEntry();
}
```

Output:

```
Entry point
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
3 5
2 6
3 7
Entry point
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
3 5
2 6
3 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a `static` variable as counter.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun()
{
    static int count=1;
    count++;
    cout << "fun() is called " << count << " times" << endl;
    if(count<=10)
    {
            fun();
    }
}

int main()
{
    fun();
}
```

`static` variables are initialized only once and the value will be retained across function calls. See this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable

Comment: Perhaps `static int count = 0;` would be better

Comment: @EdHeal - thanks, intialized `count` to 1 so that `fun()` will be called 10 times as required :)

Comment: How did you handle multiple calls to fun() in main?

Comment: I suggest to avoid static variables and go for variables passed by reference

Answer (score 1):

```
void fun(int& x){
    if(x>=10)
        return;
    ... Do something
    ++x;
    fun(x);
}
```

You should use a reference to an external variable

If you pass the counter by value you can't make multiple calls in the same function

Answer (score 0):

use static variable inside the recursive function.
static int i =0;
and in the beginning of the function, say i++.

every time the function is called, this i will be incremented. and if the value of i become 10, you can terminate.

Comment: It works, but you have to remember to reset it when exiting and hope the function isn't called from more than one thread simultaneously.

Comment: you can also wrap the bits inside the function with a static flag that says a thread is in it. This flag defaults to false. When you enter the function you first do a while( flag ) {}, and then as soon as you get past the while loop you set the flag to true, and when you are done the function you set the flag to false again. Of course a better way would be to use a kernel object like a mutex instead of a flag so that your other thread is not spinning away cpu cycles for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make it recursive...

```
void fun(int i){

    cout<<hi;
    if(i!=10) {
        i++;
        fun(i);
    }
}

int main(){

    fun(0);
}
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Sanish's solution is more elegant then mine.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am really late to answer this question. But anyway, the approach, followed by me involves **pointers** concept in #1, and **pass by reference** concept in #2. I have tested this solution for *Towers of Hanoi* problem, and it will work nearly for all kind of recursive functions in my opinion.

Actually, code written in first approach is originally in C, but it will work in C++ too, for obvious reasons.

**Approach #1**: Using **pointers in C**.

Lets say we denote the recursive function by *rf()*

1. An integer variable, lets say, with name **invocations** has to be created, to be passed to the recursive function along with other arguments (if present). It must be created in main() or the calling function. Initialize it to 0.
2. Then, in the recursive function parameter list, add another parameter with type **integer pointer**, and in the calling function, pass to recursive function, the value of this parameter as the address of the variable **invocations** defined in this calling function.
   e.g.

   ```
   void main(){

   int invocations=0;

   rf(n,&invocations); // address of variable 'invocations' is passed here
   }
   ```
3. Then, in the declaration part of recursive function, where you have added an extra parameter for counting function invocations, and declared its type as int pointer,
   in the first line of function body itself, increment the value pointed by this integer pointer by 1 in the following way,

   ```
   void rf(int n, int* invocations){

   (*invocations)++;

   /* rest of the function logic goes here */

   }
   ```

> Notice here that I have put the de-referencing operator (*), asterisk, inside parentheses in order to tell compiler to evaluate it first, as if I don't do that, the increment operator on its right will be evaluated first in absence of the parentheses (since * and ++ have same precedence, and if present in the same expression, they will be evaluated from right to left)

4. Next, print the value of invocation variable, after all the recursive function calls are over in the calling function, here in our case, inside main(). 
   Like this,

   ```
   void main(){
   ......
   int invocations=0;
   .......
   rf(n, &invocations);
   printf("\nNumber of invocations of rf()=%d\n", invocations);
   }
   ```

**Approach #2** : Using **pass by reference in C++**

All the above steps are same, only changes involved are in following ways,

1. Change the parameter type in rf() declaration from `int*` to `int&`. Like 
   `void rf(int n, int* invocations)` to `void rf(int n, int& invocations)`
2. Change the rf() call statement, pass the variable value, not its address.**(remove simply the &)**, like `rf(n, &invocations);` to `rf(n, invocations);`
3. Change the incrementation statement of *invocations* variable from `(*invocations)++;` to simply `invocations++` inside rf() body.

That's all. Both the solutions will produce same effect. Both of them works in my case.
Tell me if the solution is unclear at any step or if it fails to work in your case.