# C++ tracking number of iterations in recursive function using passed by reference method

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am trying to sort a vector of int using "insertion" method, in recursive way and passing a counter by reference (following this stack: [Keep track of how many times a recursive function has been called in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705934/keep-track-of-how-many-times-a-recursive-function-has-been-called-in-c))

Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

/*
I could do it recursively
*/
void ins_sort(std::vector<int> vec , int& counter);

void ins_sort_entry(std::vector<int> vec);

int main(){

std::vector<int> vec = {2 , 8 , 5 , 3 , 9 , 4 , 4 , 11 , 0 , -4 , -10};

ins_sort_entry(vec);
// ins_sort_entry(vec);

}

void ins_sort(std::vector<int> vec , int& counter ){

// base case 
    if (counter == vec.size() - 1){

        for (int i = 0 ; i < vec.size() ; i++){

            std::cout<<vec[i] <<", ";  
        }
    std::cout<<std::endl;

        return;
    }
    else{ 
    
        if(vec[counter + 1] < vec[counter]){ //look for a index which value is lower than vec[i], then move vec i to the index after that

            for (int j = 0 ; j <vec.size() ; j++){

                if (vec[counter + 1] < vec[j] ){

                    vec.insert(vec.begin() + j , vec[counter + 1]);//inserting vec[i] into the right position

                    vec.erase(vec.begin() + (counter + 1) + 1); //erasing vec[i] which now is vec[i+1] after insertion

                    break; //ending the inner loop after finding the first greater value
                }
            }
            
        } 
    ins_sort(vec , counter + 1);
    }
}


void ins_sort_entry(std::vector<int> vec){
    int counter = 0;
    std::cout << "Entry point" << std::endl;
    ins_sort(vec , counter);
}
```

which leads to the error below. What is the problem with this code? I even tried "const int& counter" which didnt work as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd arugment of `ins_sort` should be a variable, not calculation expression.

Instead of this

```
ins_sort(vec , counter + 1);
```

You should write:

```
++counter;
ins_sort(vec , counter);
```

Also note that you are accessing `vec[counter + 1]` even when `counter` is `vec.size() - 1`, but this is out-of-range and you mustn't do that.

Comment: Is it because it was defined as a reference?

Comment: I could fix it by making it a constant variable as "void ins_sort(std::vector<int> vec , const int& counter)"